# Problem with dropdown in Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view, drop-down-menu, razor

I have 2 table in db: MixedType(id and name) and Block(id, name, idMixedType).

I want to make strongly-typed view for Block (Create view).

Controller is following:

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Block() is a partial class (I use Entity Framework + POCO).

I have no problem with text fields, it works fine:

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.name)
    </div>
```

But I want to make dropdown for idMixedType field with values from MixedType table.

I tried to do it in following way (according to this answer [Create a Dropdown List for MVC3 using Entity Framework (.edmx Model) & Razor Views && Insert A Database Record to Multiple Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326515/create-a-dropdown-list-for-mvc3-using-entity-framework-edmx-model-razor-view)):

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.idMixedType)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.idMixedType, new SelectList(Model.MixedType, "id", "name"))
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.idMixedType)
    </div>
```

But I have a error

```
The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList.SelectList(System.Collections.IEnumerable, string, string)' has some invalid arguments
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Model.MixedType is a simple class(id, name).

Comment: It was my stupid question, I am sorry. I didn't understand the sense of Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.idMixedType, new SelectList(Model.MixedType, "id", "name")) - so, my action returned null for Model. Now, I have solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing in `Model.MixedType` to the `SelectList` constructor. Presumably `Model.MixedType` is not IEnumerable.

Is it possible it should be a lowercase "m" (model.MixedType)?

If not, you need to review the static `MixedType` property and make sure it is a collection that implements `IEnumerable` (and that the objects it enumerates have "id" and "name" properties, but I presume that's the case).