# Mvc3 add other controls

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am a new user to mvc 3. 
I read [this article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/getting-started-with-mvc3-part5-cs) to develop mvc module.
Now I want to add other controls instead of text box.
E.g. when I wish to add details in movie list.

A dropdown for genre should appear

Comment: And? What have you tried? What's not working?

Comment: i added a dropdown list in create.chtml                           <div class="editor-field">
             @Html.DropDownList(model => model.Title)
             
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>

Comment: So, why not post these details, including the error?

Comment: This will help you. Please check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326515/create-a-dropdown-list-for-mvc3-using-entity-framework-edmx-model-razor-vie

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC isn't quite like WebForms in that there's a set of server controls all ready and waiting for you to "Drag and Drop" them in your page.

In ASP.NET MVC you typically use the HTML elements as controls (often times with `HtmlHelper`s).  For instance, if you wanted a "dropdown for genre", you'd do something like:

```
<select>
  <option value="genre1">Genre1</option>
  <option value="genre2">Genre2</option>
</select>
```

Or, to generate this with an `HtmlHelper`, you'd do something like:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.YourModelProperty, YourSelectList)
```