# asp.net mvc 3 model binding dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a view with a form. On that form I have some textboxes and 2 dropdownlists.

This is my ViewModel.

```
public class NewApplicationViewModel
{
    public ApplicationData Application { get; set; }

    //Selectlists
    public SelectList Questionnaires { get; set; }
    public SelectList Jobs { get; set; }
}
```

The ApplicatoinData class looks like this

```
    public class ApplicationData
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public ApplicantData Applicant { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public QuestionnaireData Questionnaire { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public JobData Job { get; set; }
    public string Pdf { get; set; }
}
```

The "Questionnaire" and te "Job" have to be selected from the dropdownlists.
**How can a bind the selected value in the dropdown to the object in my "ApplicationData"?**
To be complete, this is my controller action to hande the form submit.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult NewApplication([Bind(Prefix="Application")]ApplicationData model)
    {
        var application = Mapper.Map<ApplicationData, Application>(model);
        _applicationRepository.Add(application);
        _session.Commit();
        return View();
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: You can specify the selected value of SelectList when you create the NewApplicationViewModel instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Html.DropdownListFor(
    x => x.Application.Questionnaire.ID,
    Model.Questionnaires
)

@Html.DropdownListFor(
    x => x.Application.Job.ID,
    Model.Jobs
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer below link for the bind drop down list. It will be very helpful to you.

[ASP.NET MVC - drop down list selection - partial views and model binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188563/asp-net-mvc-drop-down-list-selection-partial-views-and-model-binding)

[Can't get selected drop down value to bind to view model property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476372/cant-get-selected-drop-down-value-to-bind-to-view-model-property/9476794#9476794)

Here if you do not want to create property in model for the List of items, than you can also store it in a ViewData or ViewBag. Please find sample code below.

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("Category.CategoryId", new SelectList((
IEnumerable<ProductManagement.Models.Category>)ViewData["CategoryList"],
"CategoryId", "CategoryName"))%>
```