# Why is DropDownListFor not recognizing the selected value in my editor template?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, mvc-editor-templates

I have the following editor template called 'DropDown.cshtml'. The `list` part works fine, and the template uses some voodoo I did to get the required `SelectList` from `ViewData`. The controller places all select lists in the view model into `ViewData`, and there is nothing wrong with the list side of things.

```
@{
    var list = this.GetModelSelectList();
}
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model, list)
```

I use this template on foreign key view model properties like this one:

```
[Required]
[UIHint("DropDown", "MVC", "SelectListName", "JobLevelSelectList")]
[Display(Name = "Job Level")]
public Guid? JobLevelId { get; set; }

public SelectList JobLevelSelectList { get; set; }
```

In the controller, `JobLevelId` has the correct value immediately before executing the view, yet no item it selected in the rendered `select` element. or rather, the first item in the select list is always selected.

Why does `DropDownListFor` ignore the property value when used in my editor template and yet work fine when invoked directly?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039006/mvc-dropdownlist-selectedvalue-not-displaying-correctly

Comment: @RickAndMSFT, I don't see anything in that question or its answers that really applies here. The accepted answer is that the model property in the lambda of `DropDownListFor` overwrites the select list's *selected id*. That doesn't help me with my problem of the 'lambda value' being ignored only in my editor template, not in my raw DDL's.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if `ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText()` (which is what the helpers use to find property names) doesn't work with `m => Model`.

Comment: There is a fix here: https://github.com/davemorgantexas/SelectExtensionFix/blob/master/SelectExtensionFix.cs and how to use it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17474222/1751773

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is unfortunately [a known bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/654543/asp-net-mvc-possible-mvc-bug-when-working-with-editortemplates-and-drop-down-lists#details) in MVC3 (I haven't tried it in MVC 4 Beta to see if it fixed).

The work around that I have used is to manually set the [Selected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlistitem.selected.aspx) property accordingly in collection that the DropDownListFor is bound to, it is not ideal but it worked.

Comment: Thanks. off to see if I can do this workaround inside my editor template.