# MVC3 DropDownListFor not select item (Mvc bug?)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html.dropdownlistfor, mvc-editor-templates

I have simple test model:

```
  public class MyModel
    {
        public InnerModel InnerModel { get; set; }

    }

    public class InnerModel
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }
```

In controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new MyModel();

    model.InnerModel = new InnerModel { Value = 3 };

    return View("MyModelView", model);
}
```

**MyModelView:**

```
@model MyModel

@{
    var items = new List<SelectListItem>()
                    {
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "one", Value = "1"},
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "two", Value = "2"},
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "three", Value = "3"}
                    }; }


@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.InnerModel.Value,items,"no_selected")
```

When page load i see selected item:
[image]

It's good.

But if I add EditorTemplate **InnerModel.cshtml**:

```
@model InnerModel

    @{
        var items = new List<SelectListItem>()
                        {
                            new SelectListItem {Text = "one", Value = "1"},
                            new SelectListItem {Text = "two", Value = "2"},
                            new SelectListItem {Text = "three", Value = "3"}
                        }; }


    @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Value,items,"no_selected")
```

And change **MyModelView**:

```
@model MyModel
@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.InnerModel,"InnerModel")
```

When page loaded i see: [image]

Why? MVC bug?

**UPDATE:**
This real bug. [See](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10163443/why-is-dropdownlistfor-not-recognizing-the-selecting-value-in-my-editor-template?rq=1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this instead when creating the list of select items:

```
var items = new SelectList(
        new[] 
        {
            new { Value = "1", Text = "one" },
            new { Value = "2", Text = "two" },
            new { Value = "3", Text = "three" },
        }, 
        "Value", 
        "Text", 
        Model.Value
    )
```

Here is an explanation of why this happens: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11045737/486434

Comment: If it's something you do often, then put it into an HTML helper, then it will make it beautiful :)

Comment: Page you linked says "only if this lambda expression is a simple property access expression". My lambda is simple. I don't understand why it does not work.

Comment: Your're right, it is a bug in MVC, see http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/654543/asp-net-mvc-possible-mvc-bug-when-working-with-editortemplates-and-drop-down-lists#details - the solution above is a workaround. Looks like it's fixed in MVC4.

Answer (score 1):

with the @Model InnerModel change this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.InnerModel.Value,items,"no_selected")
```

to

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Value,items,"no_selected")
```

Comment: sorry, mistype. In InnerModel editor @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Value,items,"no_selected"). Correct question.