# How to Specify SelectedValue for SelectList?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, selectlist

In my MVC Project, I have a `Course` model looks like this:

```
public class Course
{
    [Key]
    public int CourseId { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

   // bunch of other properties
}
```

I'm creating a SelectList for some `Courses` in my Action

```
var user = context.Users.Include("Courses")
          .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == User.Identity.Name);
var courses = user.Courses.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
ViewBag.Courses = new SelectList(courses, "CourseId", "Name");`
```

I have a nullable `courseId` parameter in my `Action` like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? courseId)
```

If it's not null, I want to change the default selected value to that course.In order to do this I tried:

```
if (courseId != null)
{
    var selectedCourse = courses
       .FirstOrDefault(x => x.CourseId == courseId.Value);
    if (selectedCourse != null)
    {
        ViewBag.Courses = new SelectList(courses, "CourseId", "Name", selectedCourse.CourseId);
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work and `selectedCourse` is **not** `null`.Instead of specified `Course` I see the first course in my list selected every time.What am I missing ?

Edit: I'm creating `DropdownList` in my `View` like this:

```
@Html.Bootstrap().DropDownList("Courses", (SelectList)ViewBag.Courses)
```

Comment: use a null-coalescing operator `??`

Comment: You could just set the value `CourseId`, it should work. If the value is valid (e.g. `2` in a list of `1, 2, 3, 4`), it will be automatically selected in the `<select>` list.

Comment: @AmarDuplantier I updated my question with _razor stuff_

Comment: What is the value of `selectedCourse.CourseId`?

Comment: @MuraliMurugesan It's the correct id `8` in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send the selected value via your model, but, if you want to send it via viewbag, please try like so:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.CourseId, 
   new SelectList(ViewBag.Courses, "Value", "Text", @ViewBag.CourseId))
```

Please see my original answer to a similar question here for more info https://stackoverflow.com/a/16799915/1477388

Comment: I don't understand the difference but it does work :) thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If any answers solve your problem. Try it

put your selected value into a ViewBag.Seleted

```
$("#DropDownId option").each(function(){
   if($(this).val() == "ViewBag.Selected"){
     $(this).attr("selected","selected");
   }
});
```