# DropDownListFor not selecting correctly from Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Members[index].Contact.RelationId.Value, new SelectList(Model.Relations, "RelationId", "Description"), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

So my list is being created , and `model.Members[index].Contact.RelationId.Value = 2` but won't select 2nd id of the DDL only 1st.

[image]
[image]

I've tried this several different ways and stack overflow solutions. not sure what i could be doing wrong

[one of the answers attempted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16799476/mvc-dropdownlistfor-not-selecting-value-from-model)

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Members[index].Contact.RelationId.Value, new SelectList(Model.Relations, "RelationId", "Description"),  Model.Members[index].Contact.RelationId.Value)
```

without effect

Comment: When you use `DropDownListFor()` in a loop you must generate a new `SelectList` in each iteration and set the `SelectedValue` property (its an unfortunate limitation of the helper. The alternative is to use a custom `EditorTemplate` for your model and pass the `SelectList` as `additionalViewData`

Comment: @StephenMuecke but isn't that what I'm doing ( creating a New select list ) with `, new SelectList(...` per iteration? I'll try the editor template however

Comment: Your creating a new `SelectList` but not setting the setting the SelectedValue property which is necessary when used in a `for` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Members[index].Contact.RelationId.Value, new SelectList(Model.Relations, "RelationId", "Description"),  Model.Members[index].Contact.RelationId.Value)
```

It should be something like:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Members[4].Contact.RelationId.RelationId, 
new SelectList(Model.Relations, "RelationId", "Description", Model.Members[4].Contact.RelationId.RelationId), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

"m => m.Members[4].Contact.RelationId.RelationId" is where value should be saved during post back.

Model.Members[4].Contact.RelationId.RelationId is the selected value in dropdown.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, this worked as expected!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx) on MSDN, there is a constructor on the SelectList class that takes the following arguments:

```
SelectList Constructor (IEnumerable, String, String, Object)
```

Where the IEnumerable is the SelectList items, the first String is the key, the second String is the text and and Object is the SelectedValue, which is what I see you are aiming towards.

Therefore, I believe you should try this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Members[index].Contact.RelationId.Value, new SelectList(Model.Relations, "RelationId", "Description", model.Members[index].Contact.RelationId.Value), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

See if it works :)