# DropDownListFor not selecting with decimal values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I'm working with ASP.NET MVC 5 and Entity Framework 6, and I'm having a problem with the model selected value (only for decimal values) in my views.

That only happen when i'm getting data from database, if i try to submit the form, the value get back and is correctly selected.

This is my ViewModel

```
public class Regulacion
{
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ListaPorcentajePuntos 
        {
                get
                {
                        return new List<SelectListItem>
                        {
                                new SelectListItem { Text="0,625%" , Value = "0,625"},
                                new SelectListItem { Text="1%" , Value = "1"},
                                new SelectListItem { Text="1,25%", Value="1,25" },
                                new SelectListItem { Text="2,5%" , Value = "2,5"},
                                new SelectListItem { Text="5%" , Value = "5"},
                        };
                }
        }

        public decimal? PorcentajePunto { get; set; }
        //other stuff 

        public Regulacion(Reg reg)
        {
            PorcentajePunto = reg.PorcentajePunto; 
        }

}
```

And i'm using it in the view like this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.PorcentajePunto, Model.ListaPorcentajePuntos, "Please select", new { @class = "form-control"})
```

I'm pretty sure, the problem become when i fetch the data from EF and decimal precision, because, when I'm debugging, the `PorcentajePunto` property stored `5.00` instead of `5`, if i manually modify the property to `5` it works perfectly.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16799476/mvc-dropdownlistfor-not-selecting-value-from-model) question and try to use `SelectList` instead of `SelectListItem` but wasn't the solution

How can i deal with it?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I'm fetching the `Regulacion` data like this

```
using(var db = new DBTrafosContext())
{
   var a = db.Reg.FirstOrDefault();
   if(a != null){
       Regulacion newRegulacion = new Regulacion(a);
   }
}
```

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking. Both `5` and `5.00` have the same representation. Are you wanting to specifically save the selected value as `5`  instead of `5.00`, and if so why?

Comment: Saving `5.00` is correct, my problem, is when i'm retriving the `decimal` it must be `5`, other case would be `2.5`, it must save like `2.50` because decimal precision, but when i'm retriving i want to get `2.5` because `2.50` cant match to the `List` it is understood?

Comment: @StephenMuecke basically, if i try to set `PorcentajePunto = new decimal(5.00)`, `PorcentajePunto` value is `5` and it works, but if i retrive with Entity Framework, `PorcentajePunto` value is `5.00` instead of `5`, so it is not working, do you understand me?

Comment: But they are both the same value (as it `5.0000000)` - I am not sure what you are wanting to achieve - and when you save it to the db, its going to be `5.00` anyway

Comment: @StephenMuecke exactly, the problem, is that DropDownListFor() is not selecting the option when the value is `5.00` and it is selecting it ok if is `5` thats why i want to remove the extra 0 to the `decimal` and keep it as `decimal`

Comment: But why not just make it `Value = "5.00"`?

Comment: I'm actually fighting with this problem since friday and I did not think to solve it that way, thanks so much

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks! when you can, answer the question to mark it as correct!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179320/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-juan-salvador-portugal).

Comment: After a whole day of headbanging with the same problem we solved it with an extra string property to "transport" between the original decimal and the dropdown...