# DropDownListFor selectedItem not working as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

I have s simple dropdown which is rendered with:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Request.Value, new SelectList(items, "Value", "Text", selectedElement), new {})
```

where `Model.Request.Value` is of type `int` and has the value set to -1.
`items` is build like:

```
var items = new List<SelectListItem<int>>();

items.Add(new SelectListItem<int>{Text = "10", Value = 10});
items.Add(new SelectListItem<int>{Text = "25", Value = 25});
items.Add(new SelectListItem<int>{Text = "100", Value = 100});
items.Add(new SelectListItem<int>{Text = "All", Value = -1});
```

The value of `selectedElement`is 25, which is of type `int`. However, it always renders the select with `All` selected, which means value = -1.

Why? And why is there a value `selectedElement` which get's overridden no matter what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your strongly binding to a property in your model, so its the value of the property that determines what is selected. That's how model binding works. If you want `"All"` to be selected, set the value of `Request.Value = -1`

The 4th parameter of the `SelectList` constructor is ignored when binding to a property. The only time it is respected is if you were to use something like `@Html.DropDownList("NotAPropertyOfMyModel, new (SelectList(...`

Side note: `items` is `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` (which is what the `DropDownListFor()` method requires) so creating a new `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` (which is what `SelectList` is) is just pointless extra overhead. Your view should be just

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Request.Value, items)
```

Answer (score 0):

DropDownListFor uses the value of lambda expression to select the item in the dropdown list rather than the last argument of the `SelectList` constructor.

I believe that the following link includes sample code that should be able to help you:

[MVC DropDownList SelectedValue not displaying correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039006/mvc-dropdownlist-selectedvalue-not-displaying-correctly)