# Selected item for DropDownList is not working (ASP.net MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a problem with HTML.DropDownList, I´m unable to set Selected item in Edit view. I found many simmilar topics, but no one helps me find a resolution.

I will get SelectList from ViewBag:

```
SelectList sl = new SelectList(ViewBag.EmployeesTest, "Id", "DisplayName", 9908);
```

In View I will use

```
Html.DropDownList("employee",sl, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

In VS Debuger I can see list with all employees and employee with ID have property `selected = true`, but this employee is not set as selected in generated `<select>` input.

Do you have any what can be wrong?

Thanks

Alex.

Comment: Does by any chance your model also have a property named `EmployeesTest`?

Comment: No, there is no property named EmployeesTest.

Comment: @AlexB. Can you put a breakpoint on the `.cshtml` code and check wither the given id is there or not in the list `EmployeesTest`.

Comment: maybe this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039006/mvc-dropdownlist-selectedvalue-not-displaying-correctly?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: @vikscool. Yes, this ID is there and have in SelectList object property Selected = true.

Comment: @AlexB. the only reason the selected value will not be displayed on the `client-side` is when the given value does not exist in the given `IEnumerable` list. Other then that i would suggest you give us a bit more detail like a bit of your controller code where the list is created and the `.cshtml` code where you have appended the `ViewBag.EmployeesTest` to the `@Html.DropDownList`.